# Assign dynamic value to column label for lightning:datatable in JS Controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

I'm dynamically creating a table in JS Controller using lightning:datatable and it works fine. In the below code I am assigning the column label which comes as column header a static value like,  label: "Customer Id", label: "Customer Name" etc. I would like to assign an aura attribute value instead of a static string. How can I achieve this?

//CODE

```
({
    COULMNS: [
*//Need to set the label as an attribute(dynamic value) instead of static value here "Customer Id"* 
        { label: "Customer Id",fieldName: "customerId", type: "text" }, 
        { label: "Customer Name",fieldName: "customerName", type: "text" },
        { label: "Month1",fieldName: "month1Val", type: "text" },
        { label: "Month2",fieldName: "month2Val", type: "text" },
        { label: "Month3",fieldName: "month3Val", type: "text" }
    ],
    
    showTableVal: function(component,id) {
       
        $A.createComponent("lightning:datatable", {
            keyField: "Id",
            data: tableData,
            columns: component.get("v.columns"),
            hideCheckboxColumn: true
        },
                           (content, status) => {
                               if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                               component.set('v.body', [content]);
                               component.find("overlayLib").showCustomModal({
                               header: "Sales Analysis",
                               body: content,
                               showCloseButton: true,
                               closeCallback: function() {
                               // alert("You closed the alert!");
                               
                           }
                           })
    }
});
},
})*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I've not tried this out, but it should work without any issues and you may have to tweak it a bit (if needed)*. Populate or update the `columns` attribute in the init or change handler methods. For example, `init` method sample would be as follows:

Component HTML:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

Controller JS: *Note in the sample snippet I've used both aura attribute as well as constant initialized within the JS file.*

```
({
    FLDNAME: '<Field Name>',
    doInit: function(cmp) {
            var columns = [ 
                { label: cmp.get('v.<label attribute>'),fieldName: this.FLDNAME, type: "text" }
            ]
            component.set('v.columns', this.columns);
       }
})
```

If you need change the column headers after component initialization or anytime during the component lifecycle, you could declare an attribute to track changes for any of the columns headers, define a change handler and implement a similar logic in change handler method.

Although, I've mentioned only about `init` and `change` handler methods, the implementation is not limited to these JS methods and could be adopted to suit your implementation logic.